# I'm sure I'm not doing this properly as the code is so messy, access level N eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

this is the first question I post on this site, hope you can help me!

I have a fragment of code like this in my blade as below.

```
    @foreach($user->orders as $order)

      @foreach($order->orderdaytimes as $orderdaytime)

        @foreach($orderdaytime->stores as $orderdaytimestore)

          @if($orderdaytime->date == $day && $orderdaytimestore->id == $store->id)
```

The eloquent relationship is as below:
- User has many orders
- order has many orderdaytimes
- orderdaytimes belongs to many stores
- Store belongs to many orderdaytimes

as you can see in the code, i needed to loop through all these levels to find out whether there's record in orderdaytimes->store relating to a particular store.

Is there a quicker way to find out whether a given store ID exist in orderdaytimes->store pivot table.

Comment: I don't get what you want  by "a better way to do this", can you provide more details of what you're trying to do or achieve? as I can see on your codes, you have a nested loops, what's wrong with it?

Comment: HI, thank you for replying, i've added more details. I just feel i shouldn't have to nest through 3 levels to find out a piece of information...

Comment: Have you tried, array_search php function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php ?

Comment: it's not an array i don't think I can use array search?

Comment: its clearly stated on your codes, you are looping through object arrays.

Comment: else there's no way to do it but to loop on each array until you find the array node or contents that you want to find.

Comment: great!!thanks, i'll try!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the actual intermediate data, you can simply query the relationships:

```
if ($user->orders()
    ->whereHas('orderdaytimes', function ($query) use ($day) {
        return $query->where('date', $day);
    })
    ->whereHas('orderdaytimes.stores', function ($query) use ($store) {
        return $query->where('id', $store->id);
    })
    ->exists()) {
    // store id exists
}
```

You can [read more about querying relationships in the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).